# IPython3 command not found

Tags: python

After configuring and installing IPython to run under python3, as explained by this [wiki](http://wiki.ipython.org/Python_3), and having completed all the steps, I still get:

```
gmask@Gbuntu:~$ ipython3 qtconsole
No command 'ipython3' found, did you mean:
Command 'ipythonx' from package 'ipython' (universe)
Command 'ipython' from package 'ipython' (universe)
Command 'python3' from package 'python3-minimal' (main)
ipython3: command not found
```

No idea what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use "make install". Use checkinstall instead. That creates a deb package first so that you can easily uninstall afterwards.

My guess is that you installed it in a directory that's not in your path. You'll need to check the documentation for that and add it to your path manually. By the way; ipython3 is in Precise, so when you upgrade, you'll be able to simply apt-get it.

Answer (score 0):

install ipython globally

```
sudo pip3 install ipython
```

Comment: It's a little late for that command in 2021.